# Is chess.com's tactics trainer any good for actual tactical improvement?

Tags: tactics

Daniel Naroditsky recommended using this to improve at tactics but I was wondering if it was in any way worse than using a book with tactics for example.

Answer (score 2):

Its a fairly subjective question but their "learning" area is solid, the tactics tool is good for learning pattern recognition quickly. Most sites (lichess etc) have similar functionality.

Regarding how effective it is. Its dependent on you. If you learn better by doing. Probably better, if you like theory than book.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you pay the memberships the tactics on chess.com will be good. if you use the free membership you will only get 5 tactics a day. Either use lichess tactics or chesstempo. both are completely free and have many tactics.